# How to pass an input value to magento 2 from an external mobile app

Tags: ajax, magento-2.1.3

I have a mobile app currently it is in local system in the index of the mobile app I'm getting an input value ' i need to pass this input value to my custom module controller. When I put this index file in any server I can pass the value but when it is in local system there is nothing happen

> Hear is my external index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Adobe Systems Incorporated. All rights reserved.

    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
    or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information
    regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
    to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
    "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
    with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
    software distributed under the License is distributed on an
    "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
     KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
    specific language governing permissions and limitations
    under the License.
-->
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- This is a wide open CSP declaration. To lock this down for production, see below. -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <!-- Good default declaration:
    * gap: is required only on iOS (when using UIWebView) and is needed for JS->native communication
    * https://ssl.gstatic.com is required only on Android and is needed for TalkBack to function properly
    * Disables use of eval() and inline scripts in order to mitigate risk of XSS vulnerabilities. To change this:
        * Enable inline JS: add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src
        * Enable eval(): add 'unsafe-eval' to default-src
    * Create your own at http://cspisawesome.com
    -->
    <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-inline' https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" /> -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app">
        <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.jpg" width="250" height="auto" /></div>
        <h1>Update Shipping Status</h1>
        <div id="deviceready">
            <p class="event">Enter Your Order Number</p>
            <p class="event"><input type="text" id="orderNum" name="orderNum" value="" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="btn">
            <a><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="foot">
            <p>Shipping Status<br>Succesfully Updated</p>
        </div>

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
</body>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery("#shipstatus").hide();   
    jQuery(".btn").click(function(){ 
        alert("dddddddddd");
    var ordid = jQuery('#orderNum').val();
//alert(ordid); 
        var dataString = 'id='+ordid;

    alert(dataString);
        var response='';
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          async:false,
          url: "http://www.example.com/shippingstatus/index/updatestatus",
          data: dataString,
          success: function(text){
            alert(text);
          }
      });
});     
});
        </script>
</html>
```

Hear is my controller file

> /app/code/Aneka/ShippingStatus/Controller/Index/UpdateStatus.php

```
    <?php

namespace Aneka\ShippingStatus\Controller\Index;

class UpdateStatus extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{   
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->request->getParams();
     //echo $_GET['id'];
    //echo 'Hello World';
    $orderId=$this->request->getParam('id');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
    $order->setState("complete")->setStatus("complete"); 
    $order->save();
    exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject  *`\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http`* to get parameters

```
<?php

namespace Aneka\ShippingStatus\Controller\Index;

class UpdateStatus extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{   
    protected $request;

    protected $orders;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orders
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->orders = $orders;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->request->getParams();
        $orderId = $this->request->getParam('id');
        $order = $this->orders->load($orderId);
        $order->setState("complete")->setStatus("complete"); 
        $order->save();
        exit;
    }
}
```

Now clear var/generation and clear cache

Comment: please check my updated code

Comment: @Amith Try my updated answer

Comment: when i try this on server i got following errors in console  "GET http://www.example.com/shippingstatus/index/updatestatus?id=1232434 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ index.html:82
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.example.com/shippingstatus/index/updatestatus?id=1232434. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ index.html:82
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jq

Comment: @ did you check my index file